# How to repeat a character N times with printf

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a function that a pass a string. I want this function to pad this string with `*` in a line. Lets say I pass `foo bar` I want it to print something like

```
***************
*** foo bar ***
***************
```

Im running into troubles when evaluating a string length and using that with `printf`. Here is what I got

```
install_block() {
  dir="$1"
  main_echo="*** $dir ***"
  length="${#main_echo}"
  pad=$(printf '%.0s*' {1.."$length"}; echo)
  echo $pad
  echo $main_echo
  echo $pad
}
```

Comment: Quote variables! `echo $main_echo` where there are asterisks in `main_echo` does backfire with a bang.

Comment: `dir="foo bar"; main_echo="*** $dir ***"; echo "${main_echo//?/*}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use

```
pad=$(printf '%*s' $length "" | tr ' ' '*')
```

or [`jot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/jot.1.html) (install the "athena-jot" package, for ubuntu)

```
pad=$(jot -b '*' -s '' $length)
```

Also, don't forget to [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

```
echo "$pad"
echo "$main_echo"
echo "$pad"
```